# Get text from specific blocks excluding some nested tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have been trying to make a Python script which actually extracts text from a specific block of element but has to exclude some text within nested siblings.

This is my HTML part I'm trying to scrape:

```
<div class="article_body">
    <div id="articleBodyContents">
        Stack Overflow
        <br/>
        Is Love
        <br/>
        <a href="https://example_site1.com" target="_blank">Ad</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="https://example_site2.com" target="_blank">Ad2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is so far I've progressed:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
divs = soup.findAll('div', {'id':'articleBodyContents'})
for ops in divs:
    print(ops.text.replace('\n', '').strip())
```

However this prints out:

```
Stack Overflow
Is love
Ad
Ad2
```

What I want is only:

```
Stack Overflow
Is love
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there. You'd need help of `NavigableString` to achieve this. Just catch the previous parent, and iterate over it checking if the strings are an instance of `NavigableString`. Here is your code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString

html = """
<div class="article_body">
    <div id="articleBodyContents">
        Stack Overflow
        <br/>
        Is love
        <br/>
        <a href="https://example_site1.com" target="_blank">Ad</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="https://example_site2.com" target="_blank">Ad2</a>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
divs = soup.find('div', {'class':'article_body'})
ops = [element for element in divs.div if isinstance(element, NavigableString)]
for op in ops:
    print(op.strip().replace('\n', ''))
```

Output:

```
Stack Overflow
Is love
```